# Copy constructor and assignment operator both get called

Tags: c++, constructor, copy, variable-assignment, operator-keyword

I have the following program snippet:

```
Polynomial Polynomial:: add(const Polynomial b)
{
    Polynomial c;
    c.setRoot(internalAdd(root, c.root));
    c.setRoot(internalAdd(b.root, c.root));
    return c;
}

c = (a.add(b));
```

to my understanding, this code is suppose to add a and b together, then assign the resulting polynomial to c by calling the copy constructor.

however, when I actually test it,

- c calls the copy constructor right away and tries to copy b,
- then a and b add
- then c tries to get the resulting polynomial via assignment operator
- then the program crashes

what can i do to fix this?

Comment: You will need to show us the copy constructor and assignment operator to detect the reason of crash. Btw the behavior you see is more or less explainable lookup Named Return Value Optimization(NRVO).

Comment: Operator-keyword tag? Are you trying to write `Polynomial::operator +(const Polynomial& rhs) const`?

Answer (score 5):

```
Polynomial Polynomial::add(const Polynomial& b)
                                           ^
```

If you don't want the argument to be copied, pass it in as a reference as above.

This probably won't fix your crash - no way to tell what is causing that without more of your code (and some debugging on your side to pinpoint it), but it will remove the need for copy-constructing the Polynomial argument.